# How to create constraint on multiple properties in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i want to create an unique constraint involving multiple properties but i keep getting the same error executing:
`CREATE CONSTRAINT UQ_TimeGender ON (tg:TimeGender) ASSERT (tg.date, tg.time, tg.sex) is NODE KEY;`

Neo.DatabaseError.Schema.ConstraintCreationFailed
Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( timegender:TimeGender ) ASSERT exists(timegender.date, timegender.time, timegender.sex):Node(7) with label `TimeGender` must have the properties (date, time, sex)

When i check TimeGender node it has the properties date, time and sex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure all `TimeGender` nodes have all 3 properties?

You can execute this query will to check. It will return any `TimeGender` nodes that are missing some of those properties.

```
MATCH (tg:TimeGender)
WHERE tg.date IS NULL OR tg.time IS NULL OR tg.sex IS NULL
RETURN tg
```

Comment: Thank you. I had one node with null values, after deleting it everything was ok.